# How to send sms using android from my PC browser?

Tags: android

i am new to android and i am trying to build an application that would help me send an sms using android from my computer browser. for that i would even need to access my phone contacts from the browser. Can anyone suggest ways to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Ask these guys http://textyapp.com/ ;-) They use a Chrome add on and an Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a server on the device which exposes SMS sending capabilities onto the world-wide-web.

You would then build a server somewhere on the web which keeps track of the devices IP.

Finally, you would then need to build a client (web application, browser plugin, or whatever it is the you mean by "from my computer browser") which would contact the server, "the middle man", and issue SMS commands to it which in turn would contact the device and issue SMS commands to it.

Just be very careful with this because you can easily expose security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an app MobiTexter used for the same purpose https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobitexter&hl=en

Things we used for this are Google App Engine for hosting web application, C2DM for sending notifiations from our web application to the mobile app, for getting mobile inbox sms you can use ContentObserver.